# Python: Get Line pointers of all lines in a large file

Tags: python

I have a large file (6-60 GB) that I cannot load entirely into memory.
I can read it line by line:

```
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        # Do something with 'line'
```

But sometimes when I've read say the `n`th line, I need information from the `n+2`th line as well. How do I read this `n+2`th line while my 'line' object is pointing to the `n`th line?  I will still need to process the later line normally.

I'm worried if I use `f.readlines(10)`, since I don't know the size of my look-ahead (it could be 99).

I thought of one way, which would be having line pointers for each line with seek and tell in a list, but I'm worried about storage space again.

I'm looking for speed over all else in reading this file. Any suggestions?

Comment: You'd probably have to read in a couple of lines and at least store +4 lines ahead, of if you know roughly the length of each line, I strongly recommend doing `f.read(line_length*4)` and then do `buffer_lines = f.read(line_length*4).split()`. And the utilize `.seek()` as much as possible to jump around. And as @Prune said, a dictionary or list of known references, is preferrable. Either a straight up `dict` or a database that is light weight (for instance, sqlite or postgresql).

Comment: @Torxed, my issue about not knowing where n is, is a problem with what you're sugguesting.

Comment: are there any constraints you can work with?  e.g. you only ever need to see upcoming lines, or maybe never more than 100 lines either direction?

Comment: Only need to see upcoming lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as a corollary to Prune's answer a queue could do well to implement either a read-ahead buffer or a look behind, heck two queues both kept at a constant length could provide a nice middle view of what's around the current line.

Basically read the line, push on queue.
when stack reaches a certain size pop from queue and process, then push on a second queue.

when that second queue reach a given size just pop form it and forget that line.

whenever you need to look around the current line you can look ahead or look behind just by accessing values in either queues.

All this can actually be done with a simple list actually
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

to use a list as a read-ahead queue
_l.insert(0, line) to insert a line
_l.pop() to remove the line and process it

or

_l.append(line) to insert a line
_l.pop(0) to remove the line and process it

do make sure the list _l reach the desired size before calling pop
now that works only if the lines you need to keep in memory are close to the line you are trying to process.

Comment: This might be what I have to do, list.append() and list.pop(). Thank you. Holding off to see if anyone has another answer, else I'll mark this as the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea of having line references is good, and is quite efficient on storage: an integer refers to each line.  However, jumping around the file is not particularly time-effective.

Instead, I recommend that you have a read-ahead buffer.  If you're on line `n` and need data from line `n+2`, then read ahead those two lines and keep them in memory.  Finish processing line `n`.  When you're ready for the next line of input, you already have it in your buffer.

The read priority is (a) buffer; (b) fetch next line from memory.

Is that clear enough to let you progress?

Comment: How do I implement this in python?

Comment: a simple list can do all this https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: There is no "seek" with this -- you read the lines in order, placing them in a buffer (queue).  You read ahead as far as needed to process a given line.  When you're done with the line, you remove it from the queue and proceed to the next.  You can search on line for such read-ahead queues.  Asking us to provide the code without showing your attempt is out of scope for Stack Overflow.